# Crafter CMS 2.5.x Looking for client user agent

Tags: crafter-cms

I need to change the rendering of a page depending if it is a desktop client or a mobile device.
Is there any way to get the user agent in a page controller so I set a flag and use it in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to use this approach and control the template use yourself you would use the controller to look at

```
def agent = request.getHeader("User-Agent")
```